# artisan storage:link killed in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[the broken link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMy4b.jpg) and  [the output of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9DBx.jpg)
I created the folder name: "storage" in public directory then I try to run:

```
artisan storage:link
```

but it gives the message "Killed".

i want to save image in the folder storage/app/public/temporary

Any one has idea what should do?

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the file permissions. cd into your projects root folder and execute the following commands.

Change group to Apache

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage public
```

Change permissions

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage public
```

Restart Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you but i am using homestead